# Is it possible to play audio with ipod webpages?

Tags: iphone, audio, browser

I would like to have a page and either use m4a or ogg (other formats are ok but these are my preference) on my webpage. Does the ipod touch or iphone support webpages with audio? If so, is it HTML5 and what audio formats? (if html5 i'll assume i can use the audio object in javascript and not be forced to use the audio tag).

Answer (score 0):

For sure, you'll be able to instantiate a QuickTime instance to do your bidding. Can't comment on HTML5 support.

Comment: It doesnt seem to play quicktime.